# IntelliJ GUI Designer Maven Executable JAR Export

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I'm using [`IntelliJ IDEA`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)'s GUI designer and [`Maven`](https://maven.apache.org/) as build system. When I build the executable `JAR` file via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/3764804) answer, the build succeeds. However, it throws an exception when launched via the command `java -jar MyApplication.jar`:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: contentPane cannot be set to null.
            at javax.swing.JRootPane.setContentPane(JRootPane.java:621)
            at javax.swing.JFrame.setContentPane(JFrame.java:698)
...
```

The affected code line is the following:

```
setContentPane(panel);
```

When ran from source in `IntelliJ`, it works fine however `Maven` doesn't seem to properly build the `JAR` file. After all, IntelliJ does "magic" by linking to a `.form` file for keeping `.java` source code files clean from GUI code.

I also found a possible solution which involves adding a special plugin to the `pom.xml` file that seems to enable build support for `IntelliJ`'s GUI designer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877166/3764804). So I ran `mvn clean compile assembly:single` again, it didn't have any errors however nothing changed.

If I do a `mvn deploy`, the plugin throws the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:ideauidesigner-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:javac2 (default) on project MyApplication: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:ideauidesigner-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:javac2 failed: 16257 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApplication</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Commons Lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jsoup HTML parser -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.example.MyApplication
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Built-By>BullyWiiPlaza</Built-By>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- IDEA Gui Designer Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>ideauidesigner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>javac2</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What is wrong? How do I properly export an executable `JAR` file using `Maven` in combination with `IntelliJ`'s GUI designer?

Comment: I've run into the same problem. Did you solve this?

Comment: @André:
Not sure but recently I no longer had this problem and it all worked seemlessly

Comment: Seems like the problem is lambda expressions. If I remove all lambda expressions in my application, it deploys....

Comment: @André:
I also don't use lambda expressions...

Comment: Per @André 's comment, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135018/lambda-expressions-and-java-1-8-in-ideauidesigner

Comment: If anyone else is having the error with javac2 and the answer from jorichard doesnt work, try making sure you dont have any lambdas in your source code. This worked for me after jorichard 's answer didnt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem using `IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.5` but I was able to get it working with `Maven`. I created a `GitHub` repository with the updated plugin source code [here](https://github.com/jorichard/ideauidesigner-maven-plugin).

First, clone the project.

In the `ideauidesigner-maven-plugin-master` folder, run the `install-intellij-libs.sh` script to install the `IntelliJ` libraries into your local maven repository:

```
./install-intellij-libs.sh <path to your IntelliJ directory>
```

Here is also a batch file (`install-intellij-libs.bat`) for Windows:

```
SET INTELLIJ_HOME=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 173.3188.16 REM Edit this to match your path!
CALL mvn install:install-file -Dfile="%INTELLIJ_HOME%\lib\javac2.jar" -DgroupId=com.intellij -DartifactId=javac2 -Dversion=17.1.5 -Dpackaging=jar
CALL mvn install:install-file -Dfile="%INTELLIJ_HOME%\lib\asm-all.jar" -DgroupId=com.intellij -DartifactId=asm-all -Dversion=17.1.5 -Dpackaging=jar
CALL mvn install:install-file -Dfile="%INTELLIJ_HOME%\lib\forms_rt.jar" -DgroupId=com.intellij -DartifactId=forms_rt -Dversion=17.1.5 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then install your new plugin by running the following:

```
mvn install
```

Now you're done with setting up your environment.

In your actual project, edit the plugin's version in your `pom.xml` to this:

```
<version>1.0-beta-2-17.1.5</version>
```

Also add the following dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
  <artifactId>javac2</artifactId>
  <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
  <artifactId>forms_rt</artifactId>
  <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
  <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
  <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

Now building should work correctly with UI designer forms.

Comment: I'd like to thank you and the original maintainer of the sources for the compatibility fixes for newer IntelliJ-Versions. After compiling it under Windows 8 (and hopefully 10) I'm able to use lambdas again, when working with the IntelliJ-GUI-Editor and the maven-plugin.

Comment: Works. One strange thing though is that after running `mvn package` `IntelliJ` will throw the following exception when you try to run your project using the IDE: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/uiDesigner/core/Spacer` How come and how to avoid this exception? Rebuilding via `Build` -> `Rebuild Project` is a fix but why does the plugin cause the missing class?

Answer (score 17):

That happens because Maven doesn't really know how to compile GUI created with IntelliJ GUI Designer. That's why you have to explicitly instruct IntelliJ to generate all the code it understands and Maven doesn't.

To do this go to [GUI Designer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/gui-designer.html) settings and change the **Generate GUI into** value to **Java Source files**. From now on IntelliJ will include all the code responsible for setting UI up in the class itself and all the external tools, like Maven, Eclipse will work properly.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem but I think I found a much easier solution:

1. In IntelliJ go into `File -> Settings -> Editor -> GUI Designer` and do the following setting:

   - Generate UI into: Java source code
   - Enable `Automatically copy form runtime classes...`
2. Add the following dependncy into yout maven `pom.xml`:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
       <artifactId>forms_rt</artifactId>
       <version>7.0.3</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Additionally add to your `pom.xml` an assembly plugin snippet which could look like this example:

   ```
       <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                   <executions>
                       <execution>
                           <phase>package</phase>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>single</goal>
                           </goals>
                           <configuration>
                               <finalName>testUiClient</finalName>
                               <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                               <archive>
                                   <manifest>
                                       <mainClass>
                                           my.personal.MainClass
                                       </mainClass>
                                   </manifest>
                                   <manifestEntries>
                                       <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
                                       <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                                   </manifestEntries>
                               </archive>
                               <descriptorRefs>
                                   <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                               </descriptorRefs>
                           </configuration>
                       </execution>
                   </executions>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>
   ```

That should do it - it works at least for me.
Just let me know if it works also for you :-)

Comment: How can I apply this solution for Gitlab CI/CD please ? I followed your answer, but unfortunately, It does not work. I have the same error message as the OP, before the fix. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45125398) by @jorichard may be simplifed and made CI friendly - so no local installation of any IDE is required and all configuration and dependency management is done by Maven.

The plugin `org.codehaus.mojo:ideauidesigner-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1` has 2 dependencies on the code provided by Jetbrains via `com.intellij:javac2:7.0.3` and `com.intellij:forms_rt:7.0.3` (both last updated in 2008). These have not been directly updated since, but have modern equivalents hosted by Jetbrains in [their own repositories](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/intellij-artifacts.html).

All there is to be done is to overwrite the plugin dependencies. In this configuration (which is working for me) I updated to jetbrains libraries in version `212.5284.40`, or latest at the time of writing, corresponding to Intellij IDEA 2021.2.2.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>ideauidesigner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.jetbrains.intellij.java</groupId>
                    <artifactId>java-compiler-ant-tasks</artifactId>
                    <version>212.5284.40</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.jetbrains.intellij.java</groupId>
                    <artifactId>java-gui-forms-rt</artifactId>
                    <version>212.5284.40</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>javac2</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <failOnError>true</failOnError>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>intellij-repository</id>
        <url>https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>intellij-third-party</id>
        <url>https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/intellij-dependencies</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Thanks for this improvement. It helped me fix an issue with the initial answer you're referring to. Can you also explain how to get the latest versions of the IntelliJ artifacts via the IntelliJ repository?

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza the IntelliJ repositories follow normal maven repo convention, so updating version to `LATEST` keyword should work normally. Or use the same version your IntellIj, or any of these: https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/java/java-gui-forms-rt/maven-metadata.xml .
As long as you configure `pluginRepositories` portion of pom.xml, maven will handle downloading as required.