# Maven IDEA UI Designer Plugin Error

Tags: java, swing, maven, intellij-idea

**Problem:**
When using `Maven` to build a `JAR` from a project with [`IntelliJ IDEA` UI designer forms](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/designing-gui-major-steps.html#link16), the necessary designer form handling code is not compiled into the `JAR` because `Maven` is unaware of it being required. Using `IntelliJ IDEA` to build the `JAR` and/or compile the classes works.

An exception is caused on starting the `JAR` because the field is `null` without the designer "linking" it with the form:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1093)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:1005)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:567)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:417)
...
```

**Attempted solution:**
According to [this](http://glxn.net/2010/08/17/making-a-swing-project-using-intellij-idea-and-gui-builder-with-maven-including-executable-jar) tutorial, you should be able to build `JAR`s with `IntelliJ IDEA` form designer code using `Maven` but I'm getting the following error instead:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:ideauidesigner-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:javac2 (default) on project My-Project: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:ideauidesigner-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:javac2 failed: 3172 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:ideauidesigner-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:javac2 (default) on project My-Project: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:ideauidesigner-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:javac2 failed: 3172
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:ideauidesigner-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:javac2 failed: 3172
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3172
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.intellij.uiDesigner.compiler.AsmCodeGenerator.patchClass(AsmCodeGenerator.java:179)
        at com.intellij.uiDesigner.compiler.AsmCodeGenerator.patchFile(AsmCodeGenerator.java:125)
        at com.intellij.ant.Javac2.instrumentForms(Javac2.java:137)
        at com.intellij.ant.Javac2.compile(Javac2.java:50)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:820)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.ideauidesigner.Javac2Mojo.execute(Javac2Mojo.java:179)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        ... 21 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Try and run maven build with -e or -X at the end to get an error output. From the command line it would look like mvn install -e

Comment: @TylerNichols: Error output added

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747917/intellij-gui-designer-maven-executable-jar-export If that is not helpful I am sorry but I can't offer much more without a complete setup :(

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45125398/3764804) answer fixes the plugin error.