# How can I force to work option "binarry class files" in IDEA GUI Designer settings?

Tags: java, user-interface, exception, intellij-idea

I have a problem with running my GUI application, when I run my jar file. I get exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: contentPane cannot be set to null.
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane.setContentPane(JRootPane.java:594)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JDialog.setContentPane(JDialog.java:1036)
    at ui.ConnectToServerDialog.<init>(ConnectToServerDialog.java:22)
    at common.Client.main(Client.java:14)
```

This is the rather common mistake. I read solutions, but everyone writes: "choice java source code option", but it's uncomfortable for me, it fouls my code.
I talk about this settings page in IDEA:
[gui designer settings screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6ERP.png)

So, how can I fix the "binary class files option"?
I create the dialog using Swing UI Designer in IDEA

Comment: How do you compile/build the jar file? Do you use Maven/Gradle?

Comment: I use maven, it's maven project in intellij-idea

Comment: Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151118/Offical-maven-plugin-for-IntelliJ-GUI-Designer.

Comment: I also added a dependency in my pom.xml:
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms_rt</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: I added com.jetbrains.intellij.java:java-gui-forms-rt like dependency from repository https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases but it din't fix my problem

Comment: Dependency is not enough, you need to use a plug-in with javac2 goal to build the forms, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69258838/104891.