# How to initialize a Swing form created by the Intellij Designer?

Tags: java, forms, swing, intellij-idea

I have to build multiple Swing forms and I thought to speed up the process by using the Form Designer provided by Intellij IDEA.

First of all, I've created a new GUI form.
[image: Create a new gui form]

Then I added some labels, text fields and a button to the form.
[image: Content]

Now I want to add this form to another Panel. I've been checking out the Intellij help and I found [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-and-disposing-of-a-form-s-runtime-frame.html). Unfortunately it doesn't work like this. There is no accessible `contentPane` in this class, which is generated by the IDE.

[image]

What magic do I have to apply to get this to work?

Bonus question: 
Usually I extend a Swing component. For example in that case I would have something like `public class BullshitForm extends JPanel{}`. Is this possible with the Intellij Designer?

Comment: `panel1` is your `contentPane`

Comment: `panel1` never gets initialized.

Comment: And does preview work? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/previewing-forms.html

Comment: Yes, the preview works: https://i.imgur.com/MLNdqA5.png

Comment: How do you compile and run it? What is the error? You need a plugin for gradle and maven, so that the compiled form's .class file has `this.$$$setupUI$$$()`; in constructor.

Comment: I use Gradle, but I use the `idea` plugin. The stuff from the designer just never gets initialized. Maybe I need another plugin?

Comment: I know how to make it work with maven, but not sure if the plugin can be used with gradle http://stackoverflow.com/a/25877166/685796  But if you compile and run the program by IntelliJ, then it should just work anyway...

Comment: Unfortunately the form_rt.jar in maven central is very old. I think there is no acceptable solution for this at the moment. Thank you for finding the root of the problem!

Comment: you can copy that lib from IntelliJ and have it in the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the class `BullshitForm` press `ALT` + `Insert` and select `Form main()`.

Comment: This does not work when call from other class, the main form class is not initialized when main class is initialized: `contentPane cannot be set to null.`.

Answer (score 0):

i have the exact same problem as you.
I found out that the problem is that i used gradle to build my project.
After the switch to maven, everythings working now.

It seems that the gradle build process did not implement the initialication of the gui controls.